# THE TOR BROWSER AND PUBLIC EXIT NODES

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays

i wanted to run some traffic to a bunch of  websites, from **tor browser.** 
i wanna know exactly if the websites owners well detect i'am running traffic from tor, by detecting tor exit nodes. 
what software they will use to detect tor exit nodes? and would it happen frequently, like would all the websites i'am visiting, would detect tor exit nodes?

thanks for help.

Comment: Yes websites can tell that you’re accessing the website from the Tor network. They can check this by using a list of exit node IP addresses published by Tor: https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=1.1.1.1

Comment: hey, thanks! whats the proccess of doing that? , is there a software instaled into the website that detect it? or they just go randomly seraching for tor exit nodes?

Comment: You can block IP addresses with most web server software (ex: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/). You can build something a little more fancy if you wanted by pulling the latest Tor consensus and finding all relays that allow access to your server in their exit policies, and then restrict those IP addresses in your web server configuration. There are likely scripts on the internet that do this already.

Answer (score 0):

some server admins have network intrusion and network detection software that includes in itself blocking all tor IP addresses. I forgot the name, but something like suricata and all additional protection of servers.